# Get Cloudinary image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I have a model called Tile, and it has attachment:
`has_attachment :image_attachment`

I can use `cl_image_tag @tile.image_attachment.path` to display img tag but I want to get only full URL to embed is an background image in inline style, is there a way to get full URL?

``@tile.image_attachment.path returns
`v1458814322/bgo1zuv4kji17f58x5m5.jpg`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to use `cl_image_path(@tile.image_attachment)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the URL somewhere else than in a view file:

```
options = {width: 50, height: 50, crop: :fill}
Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(image_id, options)
```

Comment: Save my day. Thanks. It is really useful for my Ruby project.